# Default Classes imported in java

Tags: java, class, import, printstream

I have a simple code:

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I know that `Object` class is imported by default in every java program, but I wanted to ask whether `PrintStream` class is also imported by default if we are using `print()` or `println()` functions?

Because `Object` class belongs to `java.lang` package and `PrintStream` class belongs to `java.io` package, so if it is not imported by default, then how we are able to use the `println()` method of `PrintStream` class?

If it (`PrintStream` class) is not imported by default, then why the decompiler is importing it?

This is the output after decompiling it:
[image: Check this image]

Answer (score 1):

The types of intermediate expressions in your Java program do not need to be imported on the source code level. It's only when you assign the value of such an expression to a declared variable that you have to make its type explicit; at that moment you have to add the import (or use the qualified name).

In your case, `System.out` is such an intermediate expression; its type is indeed `java.io.PrintStream`, which is *not* imported by default as it is not in `java.lang`. If you would modify your class to

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream myOut = System.out;
        myOut.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

you need to add the import statement, or use the qualified name as in

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.io.PrintStream myOut = System.out;
        myOut.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

On the bytecode level the story is different: since all dependencies need to be loaded for the JVM to be able to execute the code, all of them are listed in the `.class` file, *including* the types of intermediate expressions. Apparently the decompiler used in the screenshot of the OP isn't clever enough to realise that such imports are unnecessary on the source code level, and so it just creates import statements for all dependencies listed in the `.class` file.

Comment: @Arend-check out the output from the decompiler.

Comment: @RajMalhotra Added a paragraph explaining the spurious import in the decompiler's output

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to ask whether PrintStream class is also imported by default if we are using print() or println() functions

No, [from the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html):

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.

So you can use `System` because [it belongs to `java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

---

> so if it is not imported by default,then how we are able to use the println() method of PrintStream class?

Because `System.out` is [accessible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) to your type, so you can use all visible method of `System.out`

Comment: @RC.-but println() is a method of PrintStream class,then how we are able to use it without importing.

Comment: To explain further (as would apply in a more generic case): when the classloader loads java.lang.System, it will process any imports that java.lang.System has, which would include java.io.PrintStream (and on and on down the line). So when you call System.out.println(), all of the needed classes are loaded and ready to go (as the most recent edit also explains).

Answer (score 0):

> why the decompiler is importing it

Looks like a bug in the decompiler you are using. This import is completely unnecessary here.

You can program without imports at all, just using the fully-qualified class names like this:

```
java.io.PrintStream out = System.out;
```

Imports are used just for convenience, so you can use simple class names in your code. It's possible that the same simple name appears in different packages (for example, `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`) so to resolve this ambiguity you have to either use full class name or import the one you want (in case you want to use both of them, you will still have to use the full name for one of them). As you correctly mentioned, only classes from  `java.lang` are imported always by default. Again, this is done for convenience, so you can use just `System` instead of `java.lang.System` (though `java.lang.System.out.println()` is also valid).

In your example as you don't directly mention the `PrintStream` in the source, no need to import it. Imports have nothing in common with class loading (which happens in runtime, not during the compilation).